# How to capture a specific portion of a screen in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

How to capture a specific portion of a screen in QML ? 
Am having a grid view where grid item contains 2 images and a text. I have to capture the grid item when click on it.
I have tried with

```
QPixmap p = QPixmap::grabWidget(widget);
QWidget p = QWidget::grab(widget);
```

But it is not working. Is there any method for this ?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Some warnings or error messages? If you are talking about QML so why do you provide C++ code? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article to learn how to post good question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because it is not a widget, not unless you use `QQuickWidget`.

You should use [`grabToImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) instead.